# How to know how many edits where made on my question?

Tags: support, editing, revisions

Is there a way to know how many edits were made on one of my posts?

Comment: In total, or on a specific one?

Comment: On a specific one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clicking on the editor's timestamp will bring up a revision list

[image: editor]

[image: revisions]

and you can expand individual revisions...

[image: revision expanded]

to give the diff

Comment: I really didnt know this. Thanks for clarifing.

Comment: welcome @Diogo_Rocha